# Error restarting when breakpoint is set in cin function during c++ debugging

Tags: c++, breakpoints, clang++, lldb, cin

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

This is my code. When you apply a breakpoint to the cin function, the following message appears:
There is a running process, kill it and restart?: [Y/n]

Please let me know why this is happening.

I use lldb as debugger

I expected the terminal to pop up or use the internal terminal of vscode, but it didn't.
Also i set "externalConsole": true.

this is my launch.json file

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [    
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            // "MIMode": "lldb"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You are already debugging another program, it just asks you if you want to stop that and start another debugging session.

Comment: The same error message appears when debugging from the beginning. I think it's a message that comes up trying to restart debugging automatically.